# Is this pythonic and what is pythonic anyway? NB: My solution passed all the test cases

Tags: python

**The question:**

Write a function called remove_duplicates which will take one argument called string.
This string input will only have characters between a-z, and should remove all repeated characters in the string.

Return a tuple with two values:
A new string with only unique, sorted characters.
The total number of duplicates dropped.

**example:**

remove_duplicates('aaabbbac') => ('abc', 5)

**My Solution:**

```
def remove_duplicates(string):
    no_dups = list(set(string))
    no_dups.sort()
    total_dups = len(string) - len(no_dups)
    return "".join(no_dups), total_dups
```

**TestCases;**

```
import unittest;

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_output_is_correct(self):
        result1 = remove_duplicates('aaabbbac')
        result2 = remove_duplicates('a')
        result3 = remove_duplicates('thelexash')

        self.assertIsInstance(result1, tuple, msg='Incorrect output type')
        self.assertEqual(result1, ('abc', 5), msg='Incorrect output')

        self.assertIsInstance(result2, tuple, msg='Incorrect output type')
        self.assertEqual(result2, ('a', 0), msg='Incorrect output')

        self.assertIsInstance(result3, tuple, msg='Incorrect output type')
        self.assertEqual(result3, ('aehlstx', 2), msg='Incorrect output')

    def test_output_is_correct_hidden(self):
        result1 = remove_duplicates('thisisateststring')
        result2 = remove_duplicates('letsseehowthisgoes')
        result3 = remove_duplicates('hiddenhiddenhiddenhaha')

        self.assertIsInstance(result1, tuple, msg='Incorrect output type')
        self.assertEqual(result1, ('aeghinrst', 8), msg='Incorrect output')

        self.assertIsInstance(result2, tuple, msg='Incorrect output type')
        self.assertEqual(result2, ('eghilostw', 9), msg='Incorrect output')

        self.assertIsInstance(result3, tuple, msg='Incorrect output type')
        self.assertEqual(result3, ('adehin', 16), msg='Incorrect output')
```

Comment: You can cut the extra `list()` by calling `sorted(set(string))`.

Answer (score 0):

Pythonic enough for my tastes, though maybe I'd write it like this:

```
def remove_duplicates(string):
    no_dups = ''.join(sorted(set(string)))
    return (no_dups, len(string) - len(no_dups))
```